# StateMachineService.acquireStateMachine shouldn't start stateMachine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

On acquiring a state machine with stateMachineService the machine is started, but I passed 'false' as a second parameter.

```
stateMachine = stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(id, false)
```

According to console output 'acquireStateMachine' starts the machine.

I'm using DefaultStateMachineService

```
@Bean
public StateMachineService<BookingItemState, BookingItemEvent> stateMachineService(
        StateMachineFactory<BookingItemState, BookingItemEvent> stateMachineFactory,
        StateMachineRuntimePersister<BookingItemState, BookingItemEvent, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister) {
    return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(stateMachineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why??

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in DefaultStateMachineService class. I suppose that you have configured SM as below enabling autoStartap property:

```
@Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {
        config
            .withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true);
    }
```

If you call acquireStateMachine the DefaultStateMachineService creates a new SM using stateMachineFactory (but you SM has enabled autoStartup) it starts a new SM and stores it to DB.

Let's consider the metnod:

```
    public StateMachine<S, E> acquireStateMachine(String machineId, boolean start) {
        log.info("Acquiring machine with id " + machineId);
        StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine;
        // naive sync to handle concurrency with release
        synchronized (machines) {
            stateMachine = machines.get(machineId);
            if (stateMachine == null) {
                log.info("Getting new machine from factory with id " + machineId);
                stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(machineId);
                if (stateMachinePersist != null) {
                    try {
                        StateMachineContext<S, E> stateMachineContext = stateMachinePersist.read(machineId);
                        stateMachine = restoreStateMachine(stateMachine, stateMachineContext);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Error handling context", e);
                        throw new StateMachineException("Unable to read context from store", e);
                    }
                }
                machines.put(machineId, stateMachine);
            }
        }
        // handle start outside of sync as it might take some time and would block other machines acquire
        return handleStart(stateMachine, start);
    }
```

To avoid this issue you may disable autoStartup option or implement you custom StateMachineService. But then you have to explicitly call stateMachine.start().